# coefficent of $Q(x)=P(x)-\frac 12x(x-1)$ are $\in Z$

Tags: polynomials

Given the polynomial $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that there is at least one coefficient wich is not $\in Z$
 And if $n \in Z$ so $P(n) \in Z$

how can one show that all coefficents of $Q(x)=P(x)-\frac{1}{2}x(x+1)$  are $\in Z$

I tried factorizing the expression but no results

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question.  I note that in the header you have $(x-1)$ which changes to $(x+1)$ in the body of the question.  I left it that way...it makes no difference to the answer.  You might want to change one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(0)\in \mathbb Z\implies c\in \mathbb Z$

$c\in \mathbb Z\;\&\;P(\pm 1)\in \mathbb Z\implies (a\pm b)\in \mathbb Z \implies 2a,2b\in \mathbb Z$

Note that $a \in \mathbb Z \iff b \in \mathbb Z$ (since $a-b \in \mathbb Z$) so your assumption implies that neither $a$ nor $b$ are integers.  Hence they are both of the form $\frac {2k+1}{2}$ and the desired result follows at once.

Comment: Is that a polynomial equation ?

Comment: Is what a polynomial equation?

Comment: I really don't know .

Comment: Not sure how to help then...which line of my answer confuses you?

Comment: The problem is that we are looking for coefficients  Q(x) not P(x)

Comment: I understand that.  The coefficients are very closely related, however.  Indeed $Q(x)=(a-\frac 12)x^2+(b-\frac 12)x+c$.  My argument shows that $a,b$ are both of the form $\frac {2k+1}{2}$ so if we subtract $\frac 12$ from them you get two integers.